# How to test angular http interceptors with injected objects

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

I am trying to test if my interceptor dispatches the correct action to an ngrx Store if a backend responds with a 419 status code - which we use to signal that a users session expired.

It is working if i try it by hand - but i cannot get a unittest to verify this. The call to my store never happens. I assume the store i spy on is not the store injected into the interceptor or i expect the call to early somehow?

This is my code so far:

```
fdescribe('Http Session Timeout Interceptor', () => {
    let store: Store<AppState>;

    beforeEach(() => {

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, StoreModule.forRoot(appReducers)],
            providers: [{
                provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
                useClass: HttpSessionTimeoutInterceptor,
                multi: true
            }]
        });
        store = TestBed.get(Store);
        spyOn(store, 'dispatch');
    });

    it('interceptor is called',
        inject([HttpClient, HttpTestingController], (http: HttpClient, httpMock: HttpTestingController) => {
        http.get('/api').subscribe(response => {
           const cast = response as HttpResponse<String>;
           expect(cast.status).toBe(419);
        });
        const req = httpMock.expectOne('/api');
        req.flush(<HttpResponse<String>>{status: 419});
        httpMock.verify();
        expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(new SessionTimeOutAction());
        }));
});
```

This is the interceptor, simply checking the response status and dispatching the action:

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpSessionTimeoutInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {}

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(req)
            .catch(response => {
                if (response.status === 419) {
                    this.store.dispatch(new SessionTimeOutAction());
                }
                return Observable.throw(response);
            }) as any;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to provide your `Store<AppState>`dependency in your providers. Not as a JSON like the `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS`, but just as a plain entry in your providers array. Also of course remove the declaration at the top. You can think of `TestBed` as your NgModule for tests. Therefore, to find a dependency to inject, Angular scans it for the tokens you need. Unfortunately, you mostly don't get helpful errors if you fail to do so.